# How can you solve this pair of simultaneous linear equations with fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on some sample quadratic equations but I am having a lot of difficulty with answers involving fractions

**Equation**

$$-3x+5y=-5$$

$$6y-5x=-6$$

**My Attempt**

Solve for $x$:

$$-3x + 5y = -5$$

$$-3x = -5y - 5$$

$$x = \frac{-5y - 5}{-3}$$

I am not sure what to do now, Can I simplify this or do I just plug it into the second equation?

Comment: You can plug your last line into the second equation, and then solve for $y$.

Comment: Where is the quadratic?  These are linear equations.

Comment: Will update this now.

Answer (score 2):

**Continuing from where you were stuck: [(Simultaneous Equations by Substitution)](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Algebra/Alg_9.htm)**

You solved for $x$ correctly, which you can simplify to:
$$x=\frac{-5y-5}{-3}=\frac{5y+5}{3}$$
You can now substitute this into the second equation:
$$6y-5\left(\frac{5y+5}{3}\right)=-6$$
Multiplying both sides by $3$:
$$18y-5(5y+5)=-18$$
$$18y-25y-25=-18$$
$$-7y=7$$
$$y=-1$$
You can now evaluate the corresponding value of $x$ by substituting this value of $y$ into one of the equations.

---

**An alternative method: [(Simultaneous Equations by Elimination)](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/algebra/alg_10.htm)**

Though, I honestly think that doing it by elimination would be easier:
$$\begin{cases} -3x+5y=-5 \\ -5x+6y=-6 \end{cases}$$
Now, multiply the first equation by $5$ and multiply the second by $-3$.
$$\begin{cases} \color{red}{-15x+25y=-25} \\ \color{blue}{15x-18y=18} \end{cases}$$
You can now add both equations together:
$$\color{red}{-15x+25y}+\color{blue}{15x-18y}=\color{red}{-25}+\color{blue}{18}$$
The $x$ terms should cancel, and you should be left with:
$$7y=-7$$
Which you can now evaluate the value of $y$, then evaluate the corresponding value of $x$.

Comment: I don't understand the second part, 18y-5(5y+5)/3 are you multiplying the 6y by the fractional 3? Do you not have to do that to the entire top fraction?

Comment: Note that $6y\equiv \frac{18y}{3}$ and that $5\left(\frac{5y+5}{3}\right)\equiv \frac{5(5y+5)}{3}$. Therefore:
$$\frac{18y}{3}-\frac{5(5y+5)}{3}=\frac{18y-5(5y+5)}{3}$$

Comment: Okay so would I be right in saying that you multiply 6y by 3 and then on the opposite side of the equals you multiply -6 by 3?

Comment: Yes, that is fine too. I edited the steps since it probably is easier to visualize that way.

Comment: Thank you thank you, what a nightmare!